# SQLAlchemy: automap_base in a forking code

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, fork

I develop an API server that interacts with MySQL DB reflecting it's schema and also get worked into multiple processes. My code for DB work looks like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session

my_engine = create_engine_by_info(my_config)
metadata = MetaData(bind=my_engine)
Base: type = automap_base(metadata=metadata)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'auth_user'
    # Relation descriptions...

# Other classes...

Base.prepare(my_engine, reflect=True)

def find_user(field):
    with Session(my_engine) as session:
        query = session.query(User)
        query = query.filter(User.field == field)
        records = query.all()
        for u in records:
            return u
        return None
```

And it works fine until process gets forked: after work of the child process the original one looses connection: `Lost connection to MySQL server during query`.

I guess I should keep `my_engine` separate for each process (e.g some function with a dict of engines where key is a PID), but how can I do that if my classes definition requires an engine at the beginning? Probably I can move classes in a function too, but it would be a hell... So, what is a good solution here?

Comment: Release all connections in use before forking (returning them to the pool), and `Engine.dispose()` of them, or at least dispose as the first thing you do after a fork.

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks for the reply! This sounds really reasonable. However, I use a framework with many abstraction levels, the code for DB work is buried far from the code which forks, so it's hard to track attach to this moment. For now I created a proxy object for the engine which checks PID and disposes the connection, it works for child processes, but the parent knows nothing about this disposal and gets errors... Probably it's better to create another service for this subtask, but it's not an option for now, so I have to make Alchemy and forking friends.

Comment: Have you read https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#using-connection-pools-with-multiprocessing-or-os-fork yet? It has some recipes for such situations that hopefully apply.

Comment: @IljaEverilä yes, unfortunately it didn't help: it led to a new connection in children, but also broke parent pool. However I created a proxy object for my engine which checks PID on `getattr` and recreates connection pool, so that child processes get their own pools, and don't dispose parent's pool, so the parent can keep working with the engine. I hope there is no memory leak.