# SQLAlchemy: use related object when session is closed

Tags: python, session, orm, sqlalchemy

I have many models with relational links to each other which I have to use. My code [is very complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63777313/5308802) so I cannot keep session alive after a query. Instead, I try to preload all the objects:

```py
def db_get_structure():
    with Session(my_engine) as session:
        deps = {x.id: x for x in session.query(Department).all()}
        ...
        return (deps, ...)

def some_logic(id):
    struct = db_get_structure()
    return some_other_logic(struct.deps[id].owner)
```

However, I get the following error anyway regardless of the fact that all the objects are already loaded:

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <Department at 0x10476e780> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'owner' cannot proceed

Is it possible to link preloaded objects with each other so that the relations will work after session get closed?

I know about [joined queries](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#joined-eager-loading) (`.options(joinedload(`), but this approach leads to more code lines and bigger DB request, and I think this should be solved simpler, because all the objects are already loaded into Python objects.
It's even possible now to request the related objects like `struct.deps[struct.deps[id].owner_id]`, but I think the ORM should do this and provide shorter notation `struct.deps[id].owner` using some "cached load".

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you access an attribute on a DB entity that has not yet been loaded from the DB, SQLAlchemy will issue an implicit SQL statement to the DB to fetch that data. My guess is that this is what happens when you issue `struct.deps[struct.deps[id].owner_id]`.

If the object in question has been removed from the session it is in a "detached" state and SQLAlchemy protects you from accidentally running into inconsistent data. In order to work with that object again it needs to be "re-attached".

I've done this already fairly often with `session.merge`:

```
attached_object = new_session.merge(detached_object)
```

But this will reconile the object instance with the DB and potentially issue updates to the DB if necessary. The `detached_object` is taken as "truth".

<strike>I *believe* you can do the reverse (attaching it by reading from the DB instead of writing to it) by using `session.refresh(detached_object)`, but I need to verify this. I'll update the post if I found something.</strike>

Both ways *have* to talk to the DB with at *least* a `select` to ensure the data is consistent.

In order to avoid loading, issue `session.merge(..., load=False)`. But this has some very important cavetas. Have a look at the docs of [session.merge()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.merge) for details.

I will need to read up on your link you added concerning your "complicated code". I would like to understand why you need to throw away your session the way you do it. Maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply! I'm afraid you've not entirely understood my Q. I don't need to deal with the DB after extracting all the data there, and the freshness isn't important (data get rarely updated). What I need is to have links between the objects. Note that I preload *all* the objects from the DB, I just want to be able to write `struct.deps[id].owner` which doesn't work for now, though the phrase `struct.deps[struct.deps[id].owner_id]` works because I have all the objects I need, but not the links between them.

Comment: The main reason to close sessions is that my code is very concurrent and forking, without closing sessions it becomes hell. The second reason is that I don't wanna mix abstraction levels: DB work and business logic. Another reason is that there is no theoretical need to perform consequent queries cuz all the objects are *already* here.

Comment: Ah right. I see now what you mean. Unfortunately I'm at a loss for that. I would have assumed that it would work via the session-identity. Did you try to just create a new session and just dumping in the objects using `session.add()` (without ever calling `session.commit()` or course)? Should even be possible with a session that's not bound to a DB to avoid accidents.